# Cygwin bash prompt is removing unexpected characters with multiline command

Tags: command-line, bash, cygwin

I repaired line wrapping in my cygwin using of the solution in [Cygwin bash prompt is wrapping lines on the same line](https://superuser.com/a/767736/1205680). However, I encountered another problem.

When a long command is posted, it's split into separate lines, as expected. For this example, I'm using a mock command `"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore"`.
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3VrY.png)

However, when I start removing characters from the end of it, the cursor doesn't appear at the end of the previous line. Instead, it appears at the end of the terminal aka last column.
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DBfQ.png)

From the user's point of view, I see that I need to first remove the whitespaces up until the word `ut` and then write `"`, but when I do that, I in fact remove also `cididunt ut"`. It looks like even though the cursor is displayed in wrong place, it removes characters as if it was initialy placed at the end of the text.
[Example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTJVQ.png)

How to fix it, so that the cursor is always displayed where it really should be?

Comment: To verify your repair, please post the output of `printf '%s\n' "${PS1@Q}"`

Comment: `printf '%s\n' "${PS1@Q}"` outputs `'\e[1;30m\w\e[0m > '` on my machine

Comment: You did not repair it. IMO the proper assignment is `PS1='\[\e[1;30m\]\w\[\e[0m\] > '`. I'm not sure if Cygwin or `cmd.exe`(?) interfere. If not then the question is a duplicate of [this one](https://superuser.com/q/367275/432690) and many others.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware that this could be the source of the problem. I'm using Windows Terminal.